# What do sun spots look like under the surface of the Sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun, elementary-particles

Do sun spots float like oil, float around like a lava lamp, is it more like the tip of an ice burg or what?

Comment: Black holes are black due to an entirely different reason when compared to sunspots.

Comment: Nor are sunspots black: they are very bright and only look dim by comparison to the even more luminous surface around them.

Comment: The second half of this post might make a decent question (why are sunspots surface effects?), but the first half and even the tags make this whole thing mostly nonsense.

Comment: Try searching for "how deep are sunspots."

Comment: @KyleKanos fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the current theory of the sun:

The top layer of the sun has convection cycles, where hot gas is rising and cooler gas is falling. (In the earth, such cycles are believed to be happening beneath the continents and causing them to push against each other.)

There are also magnetic field lines in that top layer, running north to south or south to north. There is a cycle where they start out running directly from one pole to the other, for example north to south. But the equator of the sun rotates faster than the poles (it can do this because it is a gas), and that causes the field lines to get stretched around the sun.

After eleven years, the stretching and tangling of the field lines is at a maximum, and then somehow they untangle or recombine until they run straight from pole to pole again, but now the polarity is reversed, south to north in this case. Then the differential rotation causes them to become stretched and entangled again, then the disentangle at the maximum and now they will be north to south again. This is a 22-year cycle and it keeps repeating.

Anyway - sunspots occur in pairs, and they are thought to be places where the magnetic fields in the stretched-out part of the cycle, are pushed to the surface by the rising part of a convection cycle. One sunspot is where a magnetic field line has been pushed above the surface, the other sunspot is where it reenters. This is why sunspots have an 11-year cycle.

If you look up the "Babcock model", you can find images and videos of this process.